# How to detect the presence/ absence of a PWM signal on a GPIO pin?

Tags: pwm, interrupts, detection, gpio-external-interrupt

I just want to set or clear a flag by detecting the presence or absence of a PWM signal with approximately >100 kHz frequency on a GPIO pin. I studied that a simple RC low pass filter can be used to convert the PWM signal into a voltage level and so it can be used as an external interrupt trigger for detection, but I am not quite sure if it works. Please let me know if there are better ways to do it (preferably in software). Thanks.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. If you have GPIO, you must have a microcontroller (MCU). Connect it to a timer input and use the Capture/Compare-type functions if your MCU has it to measure/check the frequency.

Comment: Are you detecting a PWM *frequency*, or just it's presence?  If the latter, treat it as a digital input and interrupt on change. Reset the interrupt after 1 PWM cycle of no detections.

Comment: OP, what's the signal from and what's detecting it for? This will help answer the question. Please edit this into your question, don't add detail in comments.